# Is the Surface Pro 2 capable of supporting a 3 monitor work station?

Tags: usb, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, microsoft-surface-pro

The Surface Pro Docking Station offers 3 USB 2.0 ports, a MiniDisplay Port, and one USB 3.0 port. I would like to use this tool with a Surface Pro 2 (Windows 8.1) to support a 3 monitor work station.

I have a limited understanding when it comes to hardware capabilities. **Is the Surface Pro 2 capable of supporting an external 3 monitor work station?**

---

Edit: Both Microsoft AND the distributor of a 5760 x 1080 total resolution 3 monitor display have confirmed that the Surface Pro 2 will support such a setup. See the great answer below for information on how to get that done.

Comment: If someone with editing capabilities would edit those links, it'd be great. I had to put them in code blocks because of my low rep.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you down-vote, at least leave a comment about how I can improve the question.

Comment: For starters, are you asking about the Surface Pro, or Surface Pro 2?

Comment: @Jason sorry, Pro 2. I had originally titled it Surface Pro Docking Station, referring to the station. Lost that detail in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really proper answer.

Due to Surface Pro 2 have an i5-4300U CPU (just like Surface Pro 3) which have integrated Intel HD4400 GPU, it [natively supports](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm) up to **three** displays over a **single** Mini DisplayPort.

The feature is called [Multi-Stream technology](http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/) and you will need either a **Multi-Stream Transport hub** (MST hub — just like familiar USB hub, but for displays) or compatible displays with a [daisy chaining](http://www.displayport.org/tag/daisy-chain/) feature.

You can use almost any combination of DisplayPort, HDMI, DVI and VGA connections (through DisplayPort adapters) and even connect one display over-the-air via [Intel WiDi](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-wireless-display.html).

Beware of USB display adapters, they will just decrease a Surface Pro 3 performance.

I made a fancy 3-Displays Options table for all Surface Pro 3 models on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface_Pro_3#External_display_connectivity), take a look.

Comment: I have been nothing but impressed with Surface Pro 2's graphic capabilities, including running Crysis 2 flawlessly, with motion blur and other nice effects enabled. Now, related to my question here, both Microsoft AND the distributor of a 5760 x 1080 total resolution 3 monitor display have confirmed that the Surface Pro 2 **will** support such a setup (albeit not while running advanced graphics on all three of them). I'm extremely surprised at this capability in a tablet computer.

Comment: Great answer, +1. Again, I'm just amazed that it works, as earlier answers to this seemed skeptical, and the question was down-voted.

Comment: I myself run 3 monitors on my Surface. Indeed, this setup works.

Answer (score 0):

The [Surface Pro 2 has one Mini DisplayPort](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-ca/support/surface-pro-2-specs).  Unless you have a monitor with a DisplayPort **output** (very rare), you can only connect one monitor.  If you're still interested in this, see [How to Daisy Chain Monitors](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/music-photos-and-video/connect-surface-pro-to-a-tv-display-or-projector#Daisy-chain).

Anything else would require USB video cards, which are more expensive and have poor performance.

Comment: That doesn't exactly answer my question.. I already know that I probably need one or more USB video card(s). I'd like to know, regardless of having super high performance, can I get this working, and how so? Will one of my solutions work? What exactly must I do? I'm willing to buy the accessories, and so long as it *works*. High FPS isn't really an expectation.

Comment: After all, it's a *tablet* (albeit a fairly high-end one) and I'm trying to utilize it in a *3 monitor* work station. If I can make it work, that's all I can ask for. I just need it to work for programming, design, and web browsing, none of which require a huge number of FPS.

Comment: @jt0dd We don't do product recommendations here.

Comment: I'm not asking for a specific product recommendation. I just want to know what category of device(s) is/are required for this to work (regardless of super performance), and the orientation in which I need to utilize it/them. I'd really appreciate the information. I'm sure there are some others out there who would benefit from such an answer as well.

Comment: @jt0dd You already said it, a USB video card.  It needs to be compatible with Windows 8.  That's it.

Comment: I see. Great! I'll try it out and up-vote this answer when I get 15 rep :)